# Find SIM Service number or sim card number in windows?

Tags: windows, cellular, wwan

I'm trying to find the SIM service number (mobile number) in windows via the command line, or powershell.

I've run through all the netsh mbn show * commands.
None show the mobile service number (eg: +6143xxxxx)

The alternative is to find the Sim card number.
The ICCID is NOT the same as the imprinting on the sims, so the ICCID number isn't helpful.

I need to audit out laptops and extract this info. I feel like it's something that should be available considering it's using the mobile service.
Really battling to find info on this via the goog, with Win10 Mob coming up a lot :(

Keen to have your help and assistant guys.

Cheers,

Comment: Why not ask for the list of the ICCID and Service Number from your mobile provider? And once you got that list, you can get the ICCID from the laptop (as you have done before) and you can cross reference that?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://supportishere.com/powershell-script-to-query-wireless-modem-and-pull-asset-information/ You should be able to skip (comment out) the registry bit down the bottom and just dump `$sPhoneNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was getting the list of device numbers + IMEIs from my carrier.

Combined with the cmd

```
netsh mbn sh interface
```

This has enabled me to get / correlate the info required.